# Dynamic Linq string 'Contains' Expression

Tags: linq, uwp

I'm trying to build a dynamic Linq expression that does the equivalent of:

```
var result = collection.Where( o => o.objectString.Contains("MySubstring"));
```

I can do something similar for:

```
var result = collection.Where( o => listOfStrings.Contains(o.objectString));
```

using:

```
MethodInfo listContainsMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.Contains) && m.GetParameters().Length == 2);
MethodInfo contains = listContainsMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
                expression = Expression.Call(contains, Expression.Constant(listOfStrings), memberExpression);
```

But I cannot figure out how to achieve the first example. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `List<T>` already has a [`Contains<T>` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-5.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be almost the same:

```
MethodInfo stringContainsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new Type[] { typeof(string) });

string sample = "abc MySubstring";
MethodCallExpression expression = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(sample),
    stringContainsMethod,
    Expression.Constant("MySubstring"));
```

The difference is that `string.Contains` is an instance method.

Comment: Thanks @mm8, I had to modify the MethodInfo retrieval to avoid an exception (more than one method met the criteria) but the rest worked.